# JSSOR non-jquery slider. empty space

Tags: javascript, slider

I am using non-jquery version of jssor slider.
When using responsive code with slides that has greater width than the width of the window, it automatically creates empty space right side of the slides(size big enough to fit the set slide width. In this case 1700px-whatever the window width happens to be)
This only happens in ie 7 8 9 10. 
Please take a look at my slide. 
http://innohome.kr

What can I do to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jssor.slider.min.js = (jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.slider.js), you can remove the following 2 lines,

```
<script src="/jssorslider/jssorcore.js"></script>
<script src="/jssorslider/jssorutil.js"></script>
```

Comment: your website is impressive, congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
<div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1700px; height: 850px; position: relative;"
id="slider1_container" class="slider1">
```

with

```
<div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1700px; height: 850px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;"
id="slider1_container" class="slider1">
```